# Routing/NAT with Network Protocol Transformation

Tags: https, router, nat

I'm looking for a way to accept multiple TCP based protocols on any port, then transform and redirect them all to HTTPS and send them over the internet to a server.  (The "Server 1" is mine with custom software and HTTPS listener, so I can receive/manipulate the packets as needed once the data gets to the server).

An example would be where 3 servers send to a single router/nat on different ports with different protocols and the router/nat sends them all over the internet as https:

```
Server A -- HTTP Port 80 ------------\
Server B -- HL7/MLLP Port 4444 ------  -- Router/NAT? -- Send all packets as HTTPS --- Internet ---> Server 1
Server C -- TCP/IP Socket Port 5555 -/
```

(the data payloads are various text messages and could be plain text, xml, json, etc.)

I know it is possible to do a port redirect, but can I also change the protocol type when forwarding (e.g. from MLLP/HL7 to HTTPS)?  Is that even needed?

A nice to have would be if the Router/NAT could inject a tag into the header so that when it gets to Server 1 the origin server (A,B,C) can be identified as the original source, if a source identifier doesn't already exist.

Can this be done?  If this exists, what are some applications that can do this today in a configurable manner? I have searched google, but without knowing what this translation is called, I have been drawing blanks.

Comment: You could set up a HTTPS tunnel. Something that that filters out the streams that you want and the tunnels them over HTTPS. Google for `IP over HTTPS`

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a VPN software?